# Changing innerHTML in php errors

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am beginner in PHP.
My CODE

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $username = "ADMIN";
    $host = "localhost";
    $password = "chmuhammadsohaib123";
    $database = "USER";
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);
    $USERNAME = $_POST["lusername"];
    $PASSWORD = $_POST["lpassword"];
    if (isset($_POST["login"])) {
        if (isset($_POST["loggedin"])) {
                setcookie("RAUSERNAME", $USERNAME);
                setcookie("RAPASSWORD", $PASSWORD);
            }
        $_SESSION["SRAUSERNAME"] = $USERNAME;
        $_SESSION["SRAPASSWORD"] = $PASSWORD;
    }
    if (isset($_POST["login"])) {
        $data = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `INFO` WHERE `USERNAME` = '$USERNAME'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($data)>0) {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.replace('../');</script>";
        }
        else {
            print("<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementsByClassName('errors').innerHTML = '<h1 class='redback'>SORRY, BUT THIS ACCOUNT DOESN'T EXISTS</h1>';</script>");
        }
    }
?>
```

MY HTML PAGE

```
<body>
    <div class="errors"></div>
        <fieldset class="replacement">
            <legend>LOGIN</legend>
            <h1>LOGIN WITH YOUR INFORMATION</h1><br><br>
            <form method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER["php_self"]; ?>">
            <input type="text" name="lusername" placeholder="YOUR USERNAME">
<input type="password" name="lpassword" placeholder="YOUR PASSWORD" class="password">
<br>
<br>
<label>KEEP ME LOGGED IN: </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="loggedin" checked>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="login" value="LOGIN"></form>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I am changing innerHTML of ***errors*** as described above, it doesn't changes. It says ***;*** is missing in console or sometimes that ***errors*** is *null*. How can I fix it?

Comment: How does the PHP relate to the HTML page?

Comment: You are open to SQL injections and have flawed login logic, you need to check the password(which should be hashed).

Comment: by requiring in php

Comment: An HTML page can't use any PHP functions unless you modified the handler.

Comment: Thanks but now my problem is resolved.

Comment: I hope this isn't a live site or going live, is it? @ChMuhammadSohaib Because if it is, your code is totally unsafe to be used in a live environment.

Comment: I haven't gone for security now, but I will do it soon after making it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the point you echo your javascript  code, the html element with the id `errors` dont exists inside the dom. So the return of `getElementById` will always be undefined.

```
<script>document.getElementById("errors")...</script>
... some more html
<div id="errors"></div>
```

You could fix this by calling the javascript code *after* the dom document is ready. Using jQuery, you could do this this way

```
// event handler for document ready
$(function() {
    // at this point, the dom is ready and the 'errors' id exists
    $('#errors').html("some error message");
});
```

This would work, but seems a little bit unnecessary. The better way would be to just echo the actual error message with php and don't use javascript to do this.

```
$error = false;
if (mysqli_num_rows($data)>0) {
    header('location: ../');
} else {
    $error = '<h1 class="redback">SORRY, BUT THIS ACCOUNT DOESN\'T EXISTS</h1>';
}
```

and later

```
<div class="errors">
<?php if ($error) echo $error; ?>
</div>
```